# I writes code of mongoose. after some time later server showing error

Tags: mongoose

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDatabase = () => {
  mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Ecommerce", {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(`MongoDB connected successfully`);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

module.exports = connectDatabase;
```

```
Server is working on http://localhost:4000
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (E:\MERN PROJECT\E-Commers WebSite\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:791:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (E:\MERN PROJECT\E-Commers WebSite\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:766:11)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

how to solve this error.

Comment: Try connecting to the database with another client (e.g. MongoDB Compass), and see whether it is the issue on the server side?

Comment: Check the mongo is running and at port `27017`.

Answer (score 0):

In node.js v18, localhost uses ipv6 address (`::1`), and by default mongodb localhost doesn't have ipv6 enabled. That's why you're facing this issue.

If you want to use ipv4 localhost address (`127.0.0.1`),

1. **Either** replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`.

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Ecommerce")
```

2. **OR (RECOMMENDED)** use `family: 4` parameter. This tells the node.js localhost to use ipv4 address.

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Ecommerce", { family: 4 })
```

**OR**

If you want to use the ipv6 address, then just start `mongod` with `--ipv6` as argument. This enables mongodb ipv6 address.

```bash
mongod --ipv6
```

Hope this helps